# Are /ɑːɹ/ and /æɹ/ allophones?

Tags: british-english, phonology, allophones

Are /ɑːɹ/ (as in "start") and /æɹ/ (as in "parody", "marry", or "clarity") allophones? It seems that the latter can only occur when the /æɹ/ precedes a vowel in the word; i.e., when the /ɹ/ would be pronounced in a non-rhotic accent even if there are no following words. I speak a variety of American English where /æɹ/ is pronounced /eɹ/, so it isn't intuitively clear to me whether /ɑːɹ/ and /æɹ/ actually are or aren't allophones.

Comment: There is a good deal of dialectal variation of vowels before American rhotic /r/. Mostly tense/lax pairs neutralize in that environment, with wide variation in actual vocalization, but non-high front vowels are famously distinct in (e.g,) Rhode Island: _Mary_ /meri/, _merry_ /mɛri/, _marry_ /mæri/. That's what my colleague Larry /læri/ from Providence told me. So the answer is really that it depends on who you're talking to and where you're from.

Comment: Rhode Island is following British English in those pronunciations. Nobody would confuse those three vowels in BrE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answer is correct. They are not allophones. But if you want even more proof, in the form of a minimal pair, the [two words](https://www.lexico.com/definition/tarry) *tarry* /ˈtɑːri/, (to be covered with tar) and *tarry* /ˈtæri/ (to delay) are a minimal pair, where the difference in these vowels distinguishes the two meanings.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not allophones or in complementary distribution. There are several words with /ɑːɹ/ followed by a vowel. The word "starrer" is pronounced /stɑːɹə/ in British English ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/starrer)), not */stæɹə/. I'd imagine "sparrer", "starring", "scarring", "charring", "tarring", etc. also have an /ɑːɹ/ followed by a vowel. All these words are derived from by adding -er or -ing; I'm not sure if there are other examples as well that aren't so derivative from another word ending in /ɑːɹ/.

Comment: There are foreign words that English has borrowed, like *safari* and *sari*, which contain /ɑːɹ/, but aren't derived from words ending in /ɑːɹ/. But I can't think of any English ones.